# Dropdown navigation items inconsistent in linking

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I created a dynamic horizontal navigational bar using SharePoint as an array of objects as a datasource.  After a bit of struggle and tons of help, I got it to work, somewhat.  I want the dropdown items to be clickable and redirect you to the link that comes from the data source but it's not doing that even though in the DOM, the item is shown as a link.  see below

```
<button class="dropbtn">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">SiteA</a>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
```

Here's an excerpt of where I build it:

```
    //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
    var itag = _createEl("i");
    itag.classList.add("fa");
    itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
    btn.appendChild(itag);
    ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

    var ddContent = _createEl("div");
    ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < subList.length; i++) {
        if (subList[i].id === subNavID.id  && subList[i].id !== "Training") {
            var li = _createEl("li");
            var a = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(subList[i].URLNAME);

            a.href = subList[i].subURL;
            a.appendChild(aTextNode);
            ddContent.appendChild(a);  
        }
    }
```

I notice that if I click on SiteC, it redirects but it doesn't do that for **SiteA** or **Training**
Can someone please explain why and a possible fix?  This has been driving me crazy for a few days now.

Here's the actual [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/oNxzxYK)